# Set TLS version to 1.2 in Twisted returns OpenSSL error

Tags: openssl, twisted, tls1.2

This is my twisted reactor:

```
def main():
    """Main reactor block, with SSL"""
    with open('configs/ssl/my_certificate.pem') as f:
        certdata = f.read()

    certificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certdata)

    # Previously the options were generated by: certificate.options()
    options = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=certificate.privateKey.original,
                                 certificate=certificate.original,
                                 raiseMinimumTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2,
                                 lowerMaximumSecurityTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2)

    factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(GMP)
    reactor.listenSSL(6060, factory, options)
    return defer.Deferred()
```

You can see here I'm trying to set TLS versions to only allow 1_2, yet I'm failing to achieve this. Everything was working properly before, when I didn't specify extra certificate options but used `certificate.options()` instead. This is the result when I run openssl to test:

```
[root@devtsm ~]# openssl s_client -connect localhost:6060 -tls1_2
CONNECTED(00000003)
140479663523728:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 70
140479663523728:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
```

I'm very new to TLS and OpenSSL so I don't really know what I'm doing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Applied this change and it works.

```
lowerMaximumSecurityTo=ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3
```

Who knew lowerMaxTo means lower it so that the maximum is the one below this value.